# Any declarative way for cloning datastructure?

Tags: c#, python, json

The project i am working at right now requires some declarative way of defining
settings for the bunch of experiments.

I have found solution like this so far.
There is some data structure that exposes default settings using JSON:

```
{
    "trustRatio": 0.7,
    "filter.coefA": 0,
    "filter.coefB": 1,
    "filter.coefC": 2,
    "filter.coefD": 3
}
```

Then to set up an experiment we have to specify which field will be changed
while running experiment. Right now i make it this way:

```
{
    "path": "filter.coefA",
    "values": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

or

```
{
    "path": "filter.coefA",
    "min": 0
    "max": 5,
    "step": 1
}
```

Then i instantiate both default and "gradient" settings as dictionaries
and use "path" key to create a bunch of experiment settings using default settings
as boilerplate and values as experiment milestones.

This solution can easily be implemented using Python or CSharp which i am working with
but its not the best one since i store default and
"gradient" settings separatly. The other thing is that i can't use 
hierarchical structure like this:

```
{
    "trustRatio": 0.7,
    "filter":
    {
        "coefA": 0,
        "coefB": 1,
        "coefC": 2,
        "coefD": 3
    }
}
```

beacause of the constraints that dictionaries put when implementing this
solution in Python and CSharp.

Does anyone knows if there is any Python or CSharp (or at least other CLR compatible language like FSharp) tool that makes possible
getting an array of experiment settings by declaring "gradient" on spot like this:

```
{
    "trustRatio": 0.7,
    "filter":
    {
        "coefA": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "coefB": 1,
        "coefC": 2,
        "coefD": 3
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Your example with a nested dictionary is already perfectly valid python. You can quickly easily test this by copy & pasting it in a python shell and seeing what happens.

Comment: You are right. But the problem is not about parsing this json into python but creating 5 separate instances of json settings with "coefA" field set 0, 1, ... 5 and not a single instance with "coefA" field initialized by array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search over web i have implemented my own solution for this problem.
It does exactly what i wanted to do. It's description can be found [here](http://yfilonov.blogspot.com/2012/05/turning-objects-inside-out.html). And CSharp source code along with some examples [here](https://github.com/Singletone/Lab).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there's a couple builtin methods for cloning dictionary structures: dict.copy() and [copy.deepcopy()](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)
Deepcopy will handle multi-dimensional dictionaries to any depth, AFAIK.
So you could have:-

```
>>> gradient = {
...    "trustRatio": 0.7,
...    "filter":
...    {
...        "coefA": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
...        "coefB": 1,
...        "coefC": 2,
...        "coefD": 3
...    }
... }
>>>
>>> gradient2 = gradient.copy()
>>> print gradient2
{'filter': {'coefD': 3, 'coefA': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'coefB': 1, 'coefC': 2}, 'trustRatio': 0.7}
>>> import copy
>>> print copy.deepcopy( gradient )
{'filter': {'coefD': 3, 'coefA': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'coefB': 1, 'coefC': 2}, 'trustRatio': 0.7}
>>> gradient.copy() == copy.deepcopy( gradient ) == gradient
True
```

Comment: As i've mentioned above the problem is not about cloning the dictionary. I just have to turn entire object inside out using the values of "coefA" array.